# Save variables in a matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, fitdistrplus

Is it possible to store variables in R..

I have to compute 10*324 `fitdist`'s which each output from this function has to be stored inside a matrix with the size above? is that possible in R?

If so then how, i am completely lost?

So i tried creating a simple example

```
norm_dist <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3))
data(iris)
for(i in 1:3)
{
  for(j in 1:3)
  {
    print(i)
    print(j)
    if(j==1)
    {
      element = fitdist(data =iris$Petal.Width[1:50*i], distr = "norm")
      norm_dist[i,j] = element
    } 
    if(j==2)
    {
      element = fitdist(data =iris$Petal.Length[1:50*i], distr = "norm")
      norm_dist[i,j] = element
    } 
   if(j==3)
    {
      element = fitdist(data =iris$Sepal.Length[1:50*i], distr = "norm")
      norm_dist[i,j] = element
    } 
  }

}
```

But i am getting this error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = list(estimate = c(0.867771222640304,  : 
  replacement element 4 is a  matrix with 2 rows, needs 1
```

I am not sure i understand what it means...

Comment: Create an example which is much smaller than 8000*324, and include it in your question.

Comment: i tried creating a simple example

Comment: data(Iris) seem to be have been added thanks  @J.Down :)
It seems pretty reproducible now..

Comment: Welcome to SO!, what Matthew meant was this [how to post a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Isn't it the case now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check out the `?fitdist` documentation under "Value" section. It mentions the output from the function which is a list with a few components.

Which of those value do you want to assign into `norm_dist`? For example, if you want the log-likelihood, you can use `norm_dist[i,j] = element$loglik`

If you want to store the whole object to be stored, you will need a list rather than a data.frame, for e.g.

```
norm_dist_res <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
    for(j in 1:324)
    {
        norm_dist_res[[paste0(i,"-",j)]] <- fitdist(data=g_all_p$data[1:8000*i, j], distr="norm")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, paste0(i, "-", j), value = list(estimate = c(0.867771222640304,  : 
  replacement has 17 rækker, data has 10`

Comment: How do i extract one single value?

Comment: 2-1 and 3-2 has the precise same input

Comment: you will need to check your indexing in `g_all_p$data[1:8000*i, j]`. I dont quite understand how you are accessing your data vector. in essence, i dont know what `g_all_p$data` is.

Comment: g_all_p$data is a matrix with 80000 rows and 324 cols 
Each 8000 belong to one class, these are observations made for one class and each row for these 8000 rows are the features extracted.  I am trying to fit each vector to a norm dist.  and save that variable in a matrix like structure.

Comment: The output matrix is suppose to have 10 rows and 324 cols.

Comment: If you want to store the whole object to be stored, you will need a list rather than a data.frame

Comment: Ohh.. wait i wrote my for loop incorrectly.. 
I have to change the row of the matrix i am searching in.. 
The first 8000  rows belong to class 0 and 8000 - 16000 belong to class 1 and so on.. the step size has to be changed in the for loop you have written.

Comment: I seem to messing things up, 

What i am doing wrong?

http://pastebin.com/fFSv42pP

Comment: try `fitdist(data=g_all_p$data[x:y], distr="norm")`. you might want to run `1+(8000*i-1)):8000*i` to understand operator precedence